# Ruby Objects from gems and where to override

Tags: ruby, rubygems, metaprogramming

So I have a gem with some activerecord objects in them, which, if it matters, are in a Single Table Inheritance hierarchy

```
# gem
class MySTIBaseClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  # some code, does NOT implement a default_scope
end
```

When I, in the Rails app try to define a default_scope

```
class MySTIBaseClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => "my_sti_bases.name ASC"
end
class MySTIOtherClass < MySTIBaseClass
  # this is not in the gem, only in the rails application
  scope :active, { where active: true }
end
MySTIOtherClass.active # order default scope is not applied
```

However, if instead of reopening the class I put the code in an initializer:

```
# initializer
MySTIBaseClass.instance_eval do
  default_scope :order => "my_sti_bases.name ASC"
end

# when the app is running
MySTIOtherClass.active # default_scope is applied
```

However, I can't really seem to understand *why* this is the case. It seems that the `MySTIOtherClass.active` isn't being called until all declarations have been evaluated anyway, so the version of the class running in the application should have the full view of all the things declared. There aren't conflicted default_scopes and it is choosing the last one declared, so it seems like the default scope should work regardless.

Answer (score 1):

The app/models directory is set as an autoload path. This means it will only require the file if it can't find the symbol. In your case, since it's already defined in the gem, the autoload will never get triggered and that is why you don't get the default_scope

Comment: Intereting! Is there any way to force rails to reload the models?

Comment: you could do something like this Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/models/*.rb").sort.each { |file| require_dependency file } in an initializer